# Matrix matplotlib associate a certain thing in a list to a row

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have created a matrix with coordinates `[(1,109),(2,21),(3,23),(4,52)...]` all the way up to around 155(the rows of the matrix go up to 155)
I also have a list of numbers `[1,1,0,2,1,3,4]` which go all the way up to 155
On a separate graph something like the second one down on this http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html I want to associate the list of numbers to the rows of the matrix. Have each number represent a different color. 1's are red, 0's blue and so on. 
Am i able to do this? if so how can i go about this?

Thank you

Comment: The example you link to shows you this can be done. But if you have any code to tell us where you got stuck, that will be much more helpful. At the moment, you show us one 2x2 matrix and a 7-element list of numbers, and we're pretty much left in the dark how you want to associate one with the other.